# Prestashop Smarty Include dies a script

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'm making a ten template for Prestahop (1.4.4.1). Any template file like authentication.tpl dies where is include:

```
{include file=$tpl_dir./errors.tpl}
```

I don't know why this is not working. I tried {include file="./errors.tpl"}, {include file="errors.tpl"} but result is same.

Thanks for every reply

Comment: What error(s) is PHP giving you? If none then is PHP set to show errors in your php.ini?

Comment: I set it to E_ALL but result is the same

Comment: I have solved this problem long time ago - problem was been in template files. I haven't copied all tpl files and some was been for older prestashop version.

Answer (score 2):

Prestashop 1.4 uses Smarty 3 as default...
so try

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./errors.tpl"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your template is located in your smarty $template_dir? If not, this page from the smarty documentation could help you: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/template.resources.tpl